# Custom UIButton class swift

Tags: swift

I was curious of how to create a custom class for a UI element (say for example, a button)?

I've read the Apple development docs and I followed the instructions, what I thought was to create a separate UIButton class file and link that class file for all buttons on the storyboard.

Here's the separate UIButton class code (file named buttonz.swift):

```
import UIKit

public class buttonz: UIButton {


    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    }

}
```

And on the storyboard, I linked that specific button to the new UIButton class:

[image]

The problem is that when I run the simulator, it gives me an error in the debig console:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key aButton

I thought the process was straightforward in the guide but am I missing any extra steps? Please let me know, thanks!

For reference, here is the link to the Apple docs that I used as a guide.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html

Edit 1 - Here's the action link to the viewcontroller.swift for the view controller. I just ctrl + dragged the button from the story board into the viewcontroller.swift.

```
 @IBAction func a(sender: AnyObject) {
        var alertView = UIAlertView();
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok");
        alertView.title = "title";
        alertView.message = "message";
        alertView.show();
    }
```

Comment: You have tried hooking up an outlet to a class in interface builder and called it `aButton`, however the class you tried hooking it up to does not have that property.

Comment: did you also make a custom controller class with property `aButton`? you will need to set your view controller class too I think.

Comment: try to remove `public` modifier.

Comment: Yes, I should modify the question to add the view controller and its class. But the button is linked as an action to the UIViewController for the viewcontroller, should I add the action link of the button to the custom class as well?

Comment: @DinoTw I don't think that will change anything?

Comment: Removing the public modifier still does not do anything.

Comment: In fact, I would leave it _public_.

Comment: You need to check your connections. You have linked outlet `aButton` from an object class that doesn't have that property defined. Look for the tiny !⃝

Comment: Did you check your button's IBAction's in storyboard by clicking the right of the mouse?

Comment: @nielsbot thank you! you were correcting in checking that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks ok, I think it's a connection error.
Open your storyboard file, select `File's Owner` (or the yellow circle on top of the view controller) and click on the "Connection Inspector" (arrow on the top right, which is the one next to the size inspector), to see all outlets at once. Look for `!`s which indicates a missing outlet.

If you're creating custom UIClasses I would suggest having a look at `IBInspectable`s and `IBDesignable`s, there is a lot about them, and enable you to do quite a bit through just storyboards, and it doesn't change your code all that much.

Some articles:

[IBInspectable / IBDesignable - NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)

[Creating a Custom View That Renders in Interface Builder - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html)

Enjoy :)

Comment: So I made a crtl + drag of the same button into the viewcontroller's code as an outlet and it seemed fine after finding that aButton was missing an outlet, thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! Good luck with it all. Do look at IBDesignables, they're pretty cool.